# How to show Categories and Sub-categories using WooCommerce

Tags: plugins

I would like to know how to display all the categories and subcategories on my WooCommerce archive-product page. (The shop index page).

I am aware you can go to the WooCommerce admin in Catalog options and tick show categories, however this displays images of the parent categories.

I am looking for something exactly like this.. http://www.simonandsimononline.com/shirts.html

As you can see on the left, I want some function to output all the categories and subcategories as links (no images).

Answer (score 2):

Sorted. It is simply done using the standard Wordpress Menu's feature in Wordpress. The same way you would create any other dynamic menu.

Make sure Product Categories is checked in screen options.